# Should two-way relations be avoided?

Tags: java, reference, design-patterns

In my java application, I have some entity, some of them may have the reference to another.

Say I have an Entity:

```
class Work{
 User manager;
}

class User{
  List works;
}
```

Then if I create one instance of Work, it will hold the reference of one user who will hold the reference of the Work.

I an afraid there will be an endless nest relation.

So I wonder if this is should be avoid or not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "endless nest relation" although it's perfectly acceptable to have a two-way relationship where each entity points to the other, both conceptually and practically.

Comment: Two way relations should not be preferred but are sometimes hard to avoid. Dangerous for example if your classes both implement toString().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with this bidirectional relationship. You seem to be worried about some kind of loop caused from traversing `User` to `Work` and back again etc.

Ask yourself whether you require to get the `Work`s given a `User` AND the `User` given a `Work`. If this is the case then it makes sense to store the bidirectional references.

Comment: agreed, but these could be methods not necessarily member variables.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with this kind of two way referencing.
The only situation I can think of where you could get into an 'endless nesting' is if the code in both classes got into a mutual calling of methods e.g.

```
class Work {
  User manager;

  public void doWorkStuff() {
    manager.doUserStuff() {
  }  
}

class User {
  Work works;

  public void doUserStuff() {
    works.doWorkStuff();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of scenario depends on the design. What kind of relationship do Work and User share? Is it 1:m, m:1 or m:n? Based on this result, we should accordingly design the class.

Based on your question, i can see 1 User can have multiple Works(List of work) but 1 Work can have only 1 user. Hence, the user in the Work class would be an entity to determine the owner of the work. Hence, name it accordingly i.e clas Work { private User owner;....}