# Annotate m:n relationship with helper class (2 foreign keys + additional attributes) with JPA 2.0

Tags: java, jpa, orm, annotations, jpa-2.0

I'm new to JPA 2.0 and have troubles annotating a n:m relationship that uses a foreign key class with additional attributes describing the relationship:

Customers can subscribe to several magazines, every `Subscription` is created for exactly one `Customer` and one `Magazine`, additionally saving the duration of the subscription.

Here are my annotated classes, I'm using field access. I've omitted some boilerplate code like constructors, setters, getters (not annotated) and the methods `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode`.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Subscription> subscriptions;

    // ..
 }

@Entity
public class Magazine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Subscription> subscriptions;

    // ..
}

@Entity
public class Subscription {
    private Date start;
    private Date end;

    @EmbeddedId
    private SubscriptionId id;

    // ..
}

@Embeddable
public class SubscriptionId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;
    @ManyToOne
    private Magazine magazine;

    // ..
}
```

I test my annotations by creating and persisting a few objects, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("kiosk");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    persist(em);

    em.close();
    emf.close();
}

private static void persist(EntityManager em) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Magazine mag1 = new Magazine("mag1");
    Magazine mag2 = new Magazine("mag2");

    Customer cus1 = new Customer("cus1");
    Customer cus2 = new Customer("cus2");
    Customer cus3 = new Customer("cus3");

    Subscription sub1 = new Subscription(cus1, mag1);
    Subscription sub2 = new Subscription(cus2, mag1);
    Subscription sub3 = new Subscription(cus2, mag2);
    Subscription sub4 = new Subscription(cus3, mag2);

    em.persist(mag1);
    em.persist(mag2);

    em.persist(cus1);
    em.persist(cus2);
    em.persist(cus3);

    em.persist(sub1);
    em.persist(sub2);
    em.persist(sub3);
    em.persist(sub4);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The provider creates the following MySQL database:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_kiosk       |
+-----------------------+
| customer              |
| customer_subscription |
| magazine              |
| magazine_subscription |
| subscription          |
+-----------------------+
```

Only the three tables `customer`, `magazine` and `subscription` have contents:

```
mysql> select * from customer;
+-------------+------+
| customer_id | name |
+-------------+------+
|           1 | cus1 |
|           2 | cus2 |
|           3 | cus3 |
+-------------+------+

mysql> select * from magazine;
+-------------+------+
| magazine_id | name |
+-------------+------+
|           1 | mag1 |
|           2 | mag2 |
+-------------+------+

mysql> select * from subscription;
+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| end  | start | magazine_id | customer_id |
+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| NULL | NULL  |           1 |           1 |
| NULL | NULL  |           1 |           2 |
| NULL | NULL  |           2 |           2 |
| NULL | NULL  |           2 |           3 |
+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

I can read my subscriptions if I know their keys. I haven't yet tried to read the whole set for a customer or magazine though.

```
private static void find(EntityManager em) {
    Magazine mag1 = em.find(Magazine.class, 1L);
    Magazine mag2 = em.find(Magazine.class, 2L);

    Customer cus1 = em.find(Customer.class, 1L);
    Customer cus2 = em.find(Customer.class, 2L);
    Customer cus3 = em.find(Customer.class, 3L);

    Subscription sub1 = em.find(Subscription.class, new SubscriptionId(cus1, mag1));
    Subscription sub2 = em.find(Subscription.class, new SubscriptionId(cus2, mag1));
    Subscription sub3 = em.find(Subscription.class, new SubscriptionId(cus2, mag2));
    Subscription sub4 = em.find(Subscription.class, new SubscriptionId(cus3, mag2));

    System.out.println(mag1);
    System.out.println(mag2);

    System.out.println(cus1);
    System.out.println(cus2);
    System.out.println(cus3);

    System.out.println(sub1);
    System.out.println(sub2);
    System.out.println(sub3);
    System.out.println(sub4);
}
```

Prints:

```
Magazine [id=1, name=mag1, subscriptions=null]
Magazine [id=2, name=mag2, subscriptions=null]
Customer [id=1, name=cus1, subscriptions=null]
Customer [id=2, name=cus2, subscriptions=null]
Customer [id=3, name=cus3, subscriptions=null]
Subscription [start=null, end=null, id=SubscriptionId [customer=1, magazine=1]]
Subscription [start=null, end=null, id=SubscriptionId [customer=2, magazine=1]]
Subscription [start=null, end=null, id=SubscriptionId [customer=2, magazine=2]]
Subscription [start=null, end=null, id=SubscriptionId [customer=3, magazine=2]]
```

The two tables `customer_subscription` and `magazine_subscription` remain empty. But as I see it they wouldn't even be necessary - the other 3 tables look exactly like I'd want them to. So my question is:

**How do I correctly model the m:n relationship used in this example with JPA 2.0 without creating excess tables while retaining the ability to write and read all subscriptions for a magazine or customer?**

In case someone is interested in the code, I've uploaded it here: http://goo.gl/qSc2e; you'll need a MySQL 5 database called 'kiosk' running at port 3306 on localhost with an empty root password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

milkplusvellocetless's answer is part of the solution, adding `mappedBy` attributes to the `@OneToMany` annotations solves the problem:

```
@Entity
public class Magazine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.magazine")
    private Set<Subscription> subscriptions;

    // ..

}

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.customer")
    private Set<Subscription> subscriptions;

    // ..
}

@Entity
public class Subscription {
    private Date start;
    private Date end;

    @EmbeddedId
    private SubscriptionId id;

    // ..
}

@Embeddable
public class SubscriptionId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;
    @ManyToOne
    private Magazine magazine;

    // ..
}
```

Creates only 3 tables (as wanted) instead of 5.

Answer (score 2):

Your model doesn't actually have any many-to-many relationships.

`Customer` to `Subscription` is one-to-many.
`Magazine` to `Subscription` is one-to-many.

Try this as your entity model:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Subscription> subscriptions;

    // ..
 }

@Entity
public class Magazine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Subscription> subscriptions;

    // ..
}

@Entity
public class Subscription {

    private Date start;

    private Date end;

    @EmbeddedId
    private SubscriptionId id;

    // ..
}

@Embeddable
public class SubscriptionId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    private Magazine magazine;

    // ..
}
```

and Hibernate won't generate the redundant link tables.

Comment: You're right about the relationship, but replacing `@ManyToMany` with `@OneToMany` didn't change the behavior: JPA/Hibernate still creates two unnecessary and empty tables `customer_subscription` and  `magazine_subscription`. Or am I missing anything else you've changed in the code?

Comment: Did you drop the whole database then let Hibernate regenerate everything? I don't see why it would behave like this.

Comment: I still had to add `mappedBy` attributes. I've added an answer of my own which includes both - using `@OneToMany` as well as the `mappedBy` attribute.

Comment: Good. It's also worth noting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964331/should-two-way-relations-be-avoided/9964381) with respect to stating bidirectional relationships.

Comment: It helped, but didn't solve the problem - for which I've now provided a full solution that I can only mark as the correct answer tomorrow. I appreciate your help and would gladly give you the point, but want to avoid confusing future readers by marking an answer as a solution that doesn't solve the whole problem.